# Jekyll Blog don't load css in github pages

Tags: css, jekyll

I've try to create a Jekyll blog using a template Jekyll ready but when I try to load to the branch `gh-pages` it don't load any resource. I've already checked the base url but nothing, someone can help me?

Link:https://bestbug456.github.io/danilogiordani.info/

Comment: All of your assets are being looked for at root level (*e.g.* `/style.css`), whereas you're actually testing this site in a subfolder, so your assets live at locations such as `/danilogiordani.info/style.css`. You'll need to either update your Jekyll config as to the actual web root, or host/test the site somewhere where it can live at root level. I'd suggest the former.

Comment: so the problem is the baseurl is incorect?

Comment: Something like that. Hard to say without seeing the config.

Comment: The config file is [here](https://github.com/bestbug456/danilogiordani.info/blob/gh-pages/_config.yml) can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *_config.yml*, add :

```
baseurl: "/danilogiordani.info"
```

Call your ressources like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/style.css">

<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

or

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/img/profile.png" alt="">
```