# My CSS doesn't render at all when I host my jekyll on gh-pages with my own domain

Tags: html, css, github, jekyll, github-pages

When I test my site on local host, the CSS and JavaScript are looking perfect. But when I push it to github repo I only see the HTML. No style. https://github.com/jaubut/website I've tried to change my URL to https://chanvrequebec.com in my config.yml. I've also try to change my `href="/css/main.css"` to `href="css/main.css"`. BUT NOTHING happens at all. I don't know what to do. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried http://jaubut.github.io/website/ ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731907/jekyll-blog-dont-load-css-in-github-pages/34732358#34732358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your website is beautifully displayed at http://chanvrequebec.com/ - not `https://` as described in your question!

If you have a SSL/TLS certificate for this domain, you'll need to change the `url` on `_config.yml` to the same protocol `https://chanvrequebec.com`

Things to be aware of:

1st. in you `_config.yml` you've set:

```
markdown: redcarpet
```

But from May 1st on, [GitHub Pages will not support `redcarpet` anymore](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0). So, I suggest you to change it to:

```
markdown: kramdown
```

2nd. Your website should be also completely accessible under http://jaubut.github.io/website, but it's not, due to mistaken configuration of GitHub Pages. You created a project website, so you'd need to set the `baseurl` to `baseurl: '/website'` to correct that. Or set the `url` to `http://jaubut.github.io/website`. But this not the best approach here, as all your internal links would redirect the pages to the `github.io` subdomain.

So, finally, to fix this properly, the best approach would be:

- Create a new repository called `jaubut.github.io` ([User website](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/))
- Transfer the content of your repo `website` into the `master` branch of the repo created on the previous step
- Keep your `_config.yml` the way it is now
- Your website will be accessible under http://jabot.github.io and also under http://chanvrequebec.com/
- Delete `website` repository
- If you have a SSL/TLS digital certificate for your domain `chanvrequebec.com`, don't forget to change the `url` on your `_config.yml` from `url: "http://chanvrequebec.com"` to `url: "https://chanvrequebec.com"`

Done!

I hope to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your website is hosted in the subfolder 'website'. The correct link for the css is href="/website/css/main.css". The correct address seems to be: http://jaubut.github.io/website. If you want a custom domain, you should use a CNAME file, see: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-pages-site-repository/.